# Customize PDF view inside a browser

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer

I've worked on a requirement that allows me to show a PDF file inside a browser by doingo a Response.ContentType = "application/pdf".

The problem is that the default view of the PDF is always showing the bookmarks menu at the left, is there a way by using HTTP headers or something to tell the PDF viewer not to show the bookmarks section?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways that you can do it. The way that I would recommend is to actually open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat and go to File, Properties. On the Initial View tab you'll see a lot of options for how to display the PDF. The second way I haven't tested but Adobe says you can pass various [querystring](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) options to the PDF. The one you'd probably want is `http://example.org/doc.pdf#pagemode=none`

Comment: pagemode was what I wanted but for some reason the querystring is not being read, anyways I ended up using PdfSharp in order to set this property and then save the output to the outputStream of the ActionResult.

Answer (score 0):

The way how a PDF document is displayed can be configured inside the PDF document.

There are a lot of PDF editors that can modify the "viewer preferences" as it is mostly called. One free example is [BeCyPDFMetaEdit](http://www.becyhome.de/becypdfmetaedit/description_eng.htm).

Comment: Ah, beat me! I didn't see the notification until right as I hit submit!